# How to implement Relation in Laravel for 3 table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 **Table** in my `database` :

1. `Product` **Table** for keep products
2. `Options` **Table** for keep products option values like colors , sizes and othe values
3. `OptionGroups` **Table** for keep group of options like size , color , memory and ...

In Options table i have product_id and optiongroup_id and a value like this : product id 1 have a optiongroup with id 2 and value X...

I wanna have **dynamic** `options` for each `product` in my `db`.

How i can write a relationship between these tables  ?

I understand about `many to many` and `many to many polymorphic` relations but this relation is different .

Finally i want have a `method` in `Product` model  to fetch `OptionGroups` and `Options` for each `product`

Any idea or solution ?

**UPDATE**
below picture is my db design : 
[image]

Comment: Hello Sam, I think you're lookig for the [hasManyThrough relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). Is it?

Comment: @AlejandroGarcía No its not a `polymorphic many to many` relation  the options table is dynamic and have value !!!

Comment: Sorry @sam, but the relation I proposed is not polymorphic. Please take a look to the edited solution. Aditionally,  I edited the response before view your model. What you have there is a many to many relation between products and optionsgroups, and products is the pivot with additional information. I will edit it again

Comment: I hope my the second edition of the response will be the approach you're looking for

Comment: @AlejandroGarcía thanks i'll test it and if work i'll say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the products options will be mixed information the best approach to do it is not any relation. Instead of it you should use a json field options inside the products table.

On migration you have yo do:

```
$table->json('options');
```

Then in the model, cast it to array

```
protected $casts = [ 'options' => 'array', ];
```

Later you can use it to filter

```
App\Product::where('options->color', 'red')->get()
```

You can find a full example using it for User meta in this link:

[Using mysql json field in Laravel](https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/)

**Edited**

Updating the response after after comment clarification.

If you don't want to use a json field, you can use [hasManyThrough relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) to do it.

In your case, one *product* has many *optionsgroups* through *options*, so you can do:

```
    class Product extends Model
    {
        public function optionGroups()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough(
                'App\OptionGroups',
                'App\Option',
                'product_id', // Foreign key on options table...
                'option_id', // Foreign key on option_groups table...
                'id', // Local key on products table...
                'id' // Local key on options table...
            );
        }
    }
```

**Second edition**

I updated the answer after the question was updated with the model image.  I don't delete the previous cause if anyone could find it useful

What is there is a many to many between Products and and OptionsGroups with products as pivot table. So according to the documentation, to retrive the groups from products, you can do:

```
    class Product extends Model
    {
        public function optionGroups()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\OptionGroup', 'options');
        }
    }
```

And the trick is on the second parameter of the relation: 'options' that has to be the name of the options table that acts as pivot in that case. Laravel can not do it automatically due table name does not respect the convention about.
Additionally is possible you have to pass extra param in order to specify the foreigns keys names you're using, like in the docu example for user and roles:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```

I think, according with your model screenshot, you'll have to do:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\OptionGroup', 'options', 'product_id', 'optiongroup_id');
```

But I suggest you read the docs about and do it accordingly to your certain real specifications.
You can find more info about it here: [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

I hope this definitely solves your problem.

Comment: i don't want to import `option` detail's in `products table` . i want use relation or something like that and in another table for create option and options group

Comment: Be careful with this one. If you use MariaDB it does not support JSON data types as of yet and this won't work.

Comment: MariaDB supports json since v10.2 @user3574492 but in any case, the another approach explained does not use json field

Comment: @AlejandroGarcía Not worked your solution , in pivot table of manytomany relation i can have one raw for relate a option to a product but in my case i must have many raw for each relation between option and product , think i have a product with id 1 and option with id 1 and this relation repet for many values like size : smal x xl xxl